# Why does pynput on MacOS Mojave report keypress 's' as Key.media_volume_down?

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

MacOS  10.14.6
Python 3.7.5
pynput 1.6.0

I am trying to capture keyboard input using pynput on my Mac, but it seems to report the following keystrokes incorrectly. Anyone know why?

```
'a' -> Key.media_volume_up
's' -> Key.media_volume_down
't' -> Key.media_next
'x' -> Key.media_volume_mute
'y' -> Key.media_play_pause
```

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import logging

log_dir = "logs"
format = '%(message)s'


logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "/log.txt"),
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=format)

def on_press(key):
    try:
        logging.info(key.char)
    except AttributeError as e:
        logging.info(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Show us the source code you're running.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/201

someone came up with a fix and if you clone the "fixup-darwin-media-keys" branch and github and install pynput manually through terminal it might worked. That is what worked for me and I am on Catalina. Hope this helps.